# Struts2 with s:action tag

Tags: struts2

Here is a small test application that does following things

1. ask user to enter his name and submit - (index.jsp)
2. as a result of index.jsp is the welcome.jsp page that asks user to select his/her blood group

index.jsp

```xml
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>   
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>   
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">   
<html>   
  <head>   </head>   
   <body>   
    <form action="MyName">   
    <s:textfield name="UserName" label="Enter Your Name"/>   
    <s:submit/>   
    </form><br>   
  </body>   
</html>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">   
<struts>   
<package name="module1" namespace="" extends="struts-default">   
<action name="MyName" class="module1.User">   
    <result>/Welcome.jsp</result>   
</action>   
<action name="Blood_Group" class="module1.SelectBloodGroup" method="bloodGroupList"/>   
</package>   

</struts>
```

SelectBloodGroup.java

```java
package module1;   

import java.util.ArrayList;   
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;   
public class SelectBloodGroup extends ActionSupport{   
    private ArrayList<BloodGroup> bglist;   

    public String bloodGroupList(){   
        bglist = new ArrayList<BloodGroup>();   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("1","A+"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("2","B+"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("3","AB+"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("4","O+"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("5","A-"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("6","B-"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("7","AB-"));   
        bglist.add(new BloodGroup("8","O-"));   
        return "SUCCESS";   
    }   

    public ArrayList<BloodGroup> getBglist(){   
        return bglist;   
    }   

}   
class BloodGroup{   
    private String id;   
    private String bg;   

    BloodGroup(String id,String bg){   
        this.id=id;   
        this.bg=bg;   
    }   

}
```

welcome.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>   
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>   
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">   
<html>   
  <head>   

  </head>   

  <body>   
    <s:action name="Blood_Group" executeResult="false"/>    

    //***************here is the problem***************   
    <s:select list="bglist" listKey="id" listValue="bg"/>   
   //***********************************************   

  </body>   
</html>
```

Struts is unable to identify `bglist` as a collection or Array or List or iterator. WHAT SHOULD I ASSIGN TO list ATTRIBUTE IN THE s:select TAG IN THE FILE welcome.jsp

What is wrong with the code please tell me in detail. If you could send me the corrected version. WHY IS THE `<s:action>` tag not working ?

This is the error i am getting

> Apr 13, 2010 1:49:19 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet jsp threw exception  tag
>   'select', field 'list': The requested
>   list key 'bglist' could not be
>   resolved as a
>   collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator
>   type. Example: people or people.{name}
>   - [unknown location]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are misunderstanding the basic struts2 flow.

The page welcome.jsp is the result page (view) for the action "MyName" (bad name, BTW). It means, when the welcome.jsp page is being generated, the action "MyName" (class module1.User) has just been "executed", and it's that object (an instance of class module1.User) the one which is in the present "scope" (the valu stack) when the result is shown. 
So, the welcome.jsp is looking for the "bglist" list in the module1.User class.

You need to rethink you action mappings.

(Your confusion can be related to your statement "as a result of index.jsp is the welcome.jsp page" ... you must think jsp pages as result of ACTIONS, not of other jsps)

Answer (score 0):

**bglist** is declared and defined in Action **SelectBloodGroup** which never comes into context.
The flow of your application is **Index.jsp(submit) --> module1.User(Action) --> welcome.jsp**, so **bglist** never got instantiated nor your class **SelectBloodGroup** got called.

If you want to use initialize your bglist in Action then place it in module1.User or you can also give values of list in jsp if these values are going to be hard coded(it seems to be) or for best practice you can use resource bundles for static values(more better than hard coding).

To give hard coded values in jsp Select List you can use the below code:

```
<select name="bgList" id="bgListId">
    <option value="1">Bpositive</option>
    <option value="someValue">someLabel</option>
</select>
```

Please try to use camelCase pattern while declaring variables.
Hope this helps.